# How to open a text file from package while application is running?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml, embedded-resource

I have a JavaFX application with a button that I want to open a "help file" I already have written, and I want it to open inside the default text editor when the user presses the button. This file is inside the package with the main FX class, the controller, and the FXML file. I've tried to do a few different things to open the file but none of them have worked. Here is the method I have currently that seems to me like it should work, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong? The name of the package everything is inside of is named "nutritionfx" just for clarification, and this code is a method inside the Controller.

```
//method to open help file when help button is pressed
@FXML private void handleHelpButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/nutritionfx/help.txt");
    File file = new File(url.toURI());
    Desktop.getDesktop().edit(file);
}
```

Comment: Wrapping a resource uri in a `File` does not make it a file. If the resource file is inside a jar and the editor expects a file, it will not gain access to the file. The only approach I know of to make the resource accessible as a file would be copying the content of the resource to a file...

Comment: So would it be best to just create a new file from the packaged file, then open that file? Will that create a new file on the users computer?

Comment: Yes, exactly, do that Trace.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example app which demonstrates the solution you proposed Trace.

> create a new file from the packaged file, then open that file

The sample app will read data out of a resource packaged with your application and save that to a local file in an application directory (named `.FileEditor), within the user's home directory.   The user can edit the text in a text editor and save the modified text to the local file.  Next time they run the application, it will read and use the modified text rather than the text from the packaged resource.

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FileEditor extends Application {

    private static final Path USER_FILE_PATH = Paths.get(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), 
        ".FileEditor"
    );

    private static final String SOURCE_FILE_NAME = "xyzzy.txt";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        if (!Files.isDirectory(USER_FILE_PATH)) {
            Files.createDirectory(USER_FILE_PATH);
        }

        Path editableFilePath = Paths.get(USER_FILE_PATH.toString(), SOURCE_FILE_NAME);
        if (!Files.exists(editableFilePath)) {
            Files.copy(
                FileEditor.class.getResourceAsStream(SOURCE_FILE_NAME),
                editableFilePath
            );
        }

        String text = Files.readAllLines(
                editableFilePath
        ).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea(text);

        MenuItem save = new MenuItem("Save...");
        save.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                Files.write(editableFilePath, textArea.getText().getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
        exit.setOnAction(event -> stage.hide());
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(
                new Menu("File", null, save, exit)
        );

        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
        layout.setTop(menuBar);
        layout.setCenter(textArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Sample source resource `xyzzy.txt`, placed into the same directory as the FileEditor.java code and copied to the resource output and packaging directory by the build system:

```
You are in a maze of twisty passages, all alike.
xyzzy
You are inside the building.
```

[image: foobar]

This sample uses a TextArea within the JavaFX application to edit the file, but you can just as easily open in the default system text editor using the construction:

```
getHostServices().showDocument(
    editableFilePath.toUri().toURL().toExternalForm()
);
```